# Application.WorksheetFunction.Match method

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen a lot of Topics to the "unable to get the match property of the Worksheetfunction class" problem. But I can't get my code fixed.

Why isn't this code work?

```
rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(aNumber, Sheet5.Range("B16:B615"), 0)
```

But a few rows higher this code works:

```
rowNum2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(originCode, Sheet7.Range("B10:B17"), 0)
```

The only difference between my two lines is that in rowNum2 I used a String for look up and in rowNum a integer.
Is it possible that the look up Value needs to be a String?

@Update on my Problem

```
Select Case service
Case "Low Cost"
MsgBox Sheet5.Cells(16, "B") 'Gets value 0.5
Set Rng = Sheet5.Range("B16:B615")

   If Not IsError(Application.Match("0.5", Rng, 0)) Then 'But jumps to Else
    rowNum = Application.Match(Weight, Rng, 0) 'Weight = 0.5
    MsgBox rowNum
Else
    MsgBox "error"
End If

Case "Standard"

Case "Express"

Case Else

End Select
```

@UPDATE 2

!!! Take care that "0.5" is a String and not 0.5
So 0.5 is not "0.5" (that was my error in the code)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are getting this error because the value cannot be found in the range. String or integer doesn't matter. Best thing to do in my experience is to do a check first to see if the value exists.

I used CountIf below, but there is lots of different ways to check existence of a value in a range.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim aNumber As Long

aNumber = 666

Set rng = Sheet5.Range("B16:B615")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, aNumber) > 0 Then

        rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)

    Else
        MsgBox aNumber & " does not exist in range " & rng.Address
    End If

End Sub
```

**ALTERNATIVE WAY**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aNumber As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long

    aNumber = "2gg"

    Set rng = Sheet5.Range("B1:B20")

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)) Then
        rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
        MsgBox rowNum
    Else
        MsgBox "error"
    End If
End Sub
```

OR

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aNumber As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Variant

    aNumber = "2gg"

    Set rng = Sheet5.Range("B1:B20")

    rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)

    If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
        MsgBox rowNum
    Else
        MsgBox "error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Alternatively instead of countif, one can also use IsError(rowNum) :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Can you expand on that alternative please? I get the same error as the OP if I try to use `If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)) Then`

Comment: The funny part is that he jumps into the if block (so the countIf works) but than the Match dosn't work ... and I get the error massage again

Comment: @user3035828 I usually use CountA to check for existence of a value, but I think in most cases it probably makes more sense to just loop through the range.. In your case, you could loop through the range and exit if you find the value. Doing a CountA check means that you are checking the range 2 times, once for the check and once to get the row value (not that I'm dissing my answer).

Comment: @SiddharthRout ahh.. I see what you did there. Key difference is the usage of `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` the latter gives the error, the first works flawlessly. :-)

Comment: In the latter, I forgot to add `Sheet5.`. You can do that :)

Comment: I mean that your method works with `Application.Match` but it still gives me the error if I use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`

Comment: oh ok :) Yes it will give an error with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and hence the vba equivalent of it `Application.Match`

Comment: Spot on though again as usual @SiddharthRout . Thanks for the info.

Comment: I'm getting crazy nothing works. I'm 100% sure that i have the Value 0.5 in that range at the first position. I can "countif" that the value 0.5 is there and I can make a MsgBox with this Value on position B16.  

So my input Says: match("0.5","B16")  How could it possibly not found this value?

Comment: @user3035828 "0.5" is not equal to 0.5 as "0.5" is a string, try changing to `Match(0.5,Sheet5.Range("B5"))`.. also, excel may display a value as rounded depending on your cell formatting, so 0.51234682 may display as 0.5 in a cell but not be equal to 0.5.

Comment: @SAM Damn your right :D That is why I wanted to convert the 0.5 to a String. If i delete the "" it works. The errors are always so simple ...