# Find then copy/past Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find/copy and past some columns from one tab to another.

This is my code:

```
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Select

code = WorksheetFunction.Match("No.", Rows("1:1"), 0)
desc = WorksheetFunction.Match("Description", Rows("1:1"), 0)
stat = WorksheetFunction.Match("Item Status", Rows("1:1"), 0)
sale = WorksheetFunction.Match("Qty. on Sales Order", Rows("1:1"), 0)
purc = WorksheetFunction.Match("Qty. on Purch. Order", Rows("1:1"), 0)
inv = WorksheetFunction.Match("Inventory", Rows("1:1"), 0)
**meas = WorksheetFunction.Match("Base Unit of Measure", Rows("1:1"), 0)**

Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(code).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("A1")
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(desc).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("B1")
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(stat).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("C1")
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(sale).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("D1")
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(purc).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("E1")
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(inv).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("F1")
Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(meas).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("G1")
```

)

I always get an error on this line **, if I delete it the code works fine.

**Can You Please Help**

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, and thanks for replying. That's my problem I can't understand why is giving me an error :(

Comment: Run-time error '1004' - unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class

Comment: Then this "Base Unit of Measure" can't be found.  You should check for it first.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214540/application-worksheetfunction-match-method) on how to check first.

Comment: @mrbungle "Base Unit of Measure" is there, I have copy it from the spreadsheet to the code, I don't really undestand...

Comment: can the string (column header) to long???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to do this for each one.  If there's no match it just skips it.  You might want to add a MsgBox to alert you or fill the cell with a msg stating Not Found or something to that affect. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873(v=office.15).aspx) for more info.

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("Description", Rows("1:1"), 0)) Then
    desc = Application.Match("Description", Rows("1:1"), 0)
    Sheets("Past Inventory Here").Columns(desc).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Inventory").Range("B1")
else
    MsgBox " does not exist in range "
End If
```

Comment: @rui I added the `else msgbox`. step through it and see if it pops down to the msgbox.

Comment: yes it pops down, but the "Base Unit of Measure" is there on column L, I don't understand why all the others work but this one, can the string "Base Unit of Measure" be to long???

Comment: Perhaps changing the Match_type varialble at the end.  The ,`Rows("1:1"),0)`  (the 0 looking for an exact match).  Change it to -1 or 1 and see if it changes the outcome.

Comment: You might want to find a way to share your file because I think from this format we've covered just about anything that would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the title is not exactly the same. Is there a blank in the beginning or the end of the "Base Unit of Measure"? 
If you know exactly where it is (let"s say in L1 fore instance), you can try the below code. Just add it before you try to set the meas variable. In the popup, you will get the text so you can compare letter by letter that they are identical. The > at the end needs to be exactly in line with each other:

```
MsgBox "<Base Unit of Measure> = " & Len("Base Unit of Measure") _
  & vbNewLine _
  & "<" & Range("L1").Value & "> = " & Len(Range("L1").Value)
```

Comment: I had not tested the code, as I was on a device where I did not have excel. The above code is now working.