# Refer to a column using the column header rather than column number

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this spreadsheet with different columns of data in them. One of the column is titled "States" and it has the abbreviation for different states in that column. Another column is titled, "Last_IVR" and it either have rows that say "Completed" or they say "Not Completed". I have written a code that filters these two columns based on states or whether its completed or not. But the one problem I am running into is that not every spreadsheet have the States column at the same position. What I mean by this is that, lets say on the first worksheet, "States" is in column "F" but in another spreadsheet, "States" could be in column "C". So is there a way, I can manipulate my code below so it is referring to the column header rather than the column number. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    Sub CFunctions() 
        Dim LR As Long
        LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        Dim State As Range
        Dim Last_IVR As Range


        'Removes rows that says "Complete"

        For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        Set Last_IVR = Range("G" & i)
        If InStr(Last_IVR, "Complete") >= 1 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        End If
        Next i

        'Removes all states that are not "TX"

        For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        Set State = Range("F" & i)
        If InStr(State, "TX") = 0 Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        End If
        Next i
        MsgBox "Completed"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use match just like the spreadsheet function to search for your header in the first row.

Syntax and more properties can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx
or here:
[Application.WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214540/application-worksheetfunction-match-method)

Once the index is returned to you form the match function, you can use the number to reference ranges in the cells(x,y) notation.

```
Application.worksheetfunction.match("State", [range referencing rows of headers],0)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks Kory. Another question I had was, do you think its possible to return the letter of the column rather than the number of the index? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kory, when I use this, it  gives me an error stating that "Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class" Error 1004

Comment: Can you try just Application.Match?

Answer (score 0):

I had this function that would return the Column letter when you entered its number as a parameter:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Integer) As String
'Returns the column letter using its number as parameter
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Hope this helps!