# VBA Match function with ActiveSheet

Tags: vba

The script works fine if i put: `ThisWorkbook` but with `ActiveWorkbook`  doesn't work.

Error `1004` say: "`Unable to get the Match property of the Worksheet function class`"

```
Dim dat As Date

calea_livrat = "my link" & ".xlsx"
Workbooks.Open calea_livrat

With ActiveWorkbook
    dat = zi & "-" & luna & "-" & an
    data_gen = CDbl(dat)
    nr_linie = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(data_gen, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A"), 0)
    MsgBox nr_linie
End With
```

Something is wrong here: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(data_gen, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A"), 0)` but i can't figure out what.

Comment: First: Please fix the syntax error in your sample code. Second: What's the purpose of that `With` block? None of your code uses it. Remove it or use use it.

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214540/application-worksheetfunction-match-method
Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398310/match-function-in-vba

Comment: My code, open an excel file and with that file opened i need to `Match` something. That Match doesn't work property

Comment: @Marius post the rest of your relevant code, maybe we can help you avoid the error there. Yyu are already inside `With ActiveWorkbook`, why do you need `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A")` ? why not `.Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A")` ?  And last, what do you do in case `Match` function is unable to find a match ? how do you handle this error ?
`

Comment: @shai-rado The rest of the code is not relevant, everything is work if I put `ThisWorksheet` instead `ActiveWorkbook` or  `ActiveSheet`

Comment: I've tried `.Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A")` and still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer, just how to use `Match` function in your case properly:

```
Dim nr_linie As Variant

With ActiveWorkbook
    dat = zi & "-" & luna & "-" & an
    data_gen = CDbl(dat)

    ' in case Match was able to find data_gen in Column A
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(data_gen, .Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
        nr_linie = Application.Match(data_gen, .Worksheets("PE_Centralizare").Range("A:A"), 0)
        MsgBox "Row number " & data_gen & " value was found in row " & nr_linie
    Else ' <-- Macth failed, unable to find find data_gen in Column A
        MsgBox data_gen & " value not found in Range !"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the next step .

Comment: Did you insert this code into yours ? is it working now ?

Comment: The problem was here: instead of `nr_linie = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(data_gen` I put :`nr_linie = Application.Match(data_gen` Thank you!