# VBA - horizontal lookup across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following lookup sheet (named "Formatting"):
https://ethercalc.org/zs2n0j4u9xdi

I'm iterating over a column in a different sheet, where I'm getting values that are equivalent with those in the "item" column above. I want to look up these nicknames into the sheet above, and acquire the two values to the left of them, and store them in two variables:

This is my code which gets me these "items":

```
i = 7
currRow = 9
While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Cells(i, 3) <> ""
    Item = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weights").Cells(i, 3).Value
    parent = someLookupMethod("Formatting", Item)
    child = someLookupMethod("Formatting", Item)
    currRow = currRow + 1
    i = i + 1

Wend
```

How would I implement this?

Comment: Using Match method over a range to get the row # is one method.  The question is if you are matching to a table (multi row, multi column) or column to column and then taking data out of adjacent columns.https://stackoverflow.com/a/20214674/8716187

Comment: I would be matching a cell value to a column to find a row number, but then this begs the question how would I use that row number to get the column values I need?

Comment: Do you know the layout of your data?  I built a quick demo below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of one way to use Find to get the Row match for your data.
I put the trigger for the search into a command button here ( I did not bother to name the button).

NOTE: The code below was done quickly, hard coding cell coordinates is not the best way to use addresses as it is not flexible.  If you don't know the size of your data you find the last column and the last row and define the data range using those numbers.

Note2: To forego the worksheet variable creation and naming, I simply gave the sheets code names in the Properties window, very fast to code things up this way.

The code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Fname As String
Dim MatchRow As Double
Dim MatchRange As Range
'wsSearch named worksheet, you no longer have to care about the WS tab name
'wsData is a named worksheet, you no longer have to care about the WS tab name
'Do this using the properties explorer in design mode (under developer)
'Or create and set your worksheets ... sometimes you have to

Fname = CStr(wsSearch.Cells(2, 3)) 'convert that cell to a string (row, column)

'This simply clears the cells so old search data is not present
wsSearch.Range("C3:C6").Clear
                            
If wsSearch.Cells(2, 3) <> "" Then 'Test there is a name to search
    Set MatchRange = wsData.Range("A1:D10").Find(Fname)
    
    If (Not MatchRange Is Nothing) Then
        'We have a match
        MatchRow = MatchRange.Row 'assign MatchRow and now you can use it in .Cells or .Range definitions
        
        wsSearch.Cells(3, 3) = MatchRow  'Report MatchRow
        wsSearch.Cells(4, 3) = wsData.Cells(MatchRow, 2) 'Report Last name
        wsSearch.Cells(5, 3) = wsData.Cells(MatchRow, 3) 'Report Address
        wsSearch.Cells(6, 3) = wsData.Cells(MatchRow, 4) 'Report Phone
        
        'left justify everything, by default numbers are right justified
        wsSearch.Range("C3:C6").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Else
        wsSearch.Cells(3, 3) = "NA"
        wsSearch.Cells(4, 3) = "NA"
        wsSearch.Cells(5, 3) = "NA"
        wsSearch.Cells(6, 3) = "NA"
        
        MsgBox "The name " & Fname & " was not found"
        
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No Name to Search, try again"
End If

End Sub
```

This is what the Worksheets look like:

wsSearch
[image]
wsData
[image]

You will find the greater challenges are defining what the data range is and its layout, as well as where to put the data and its layout as you build your application out.

Happy Coding!

If this helps you, accept the answer - WWC